# How to use a list of records as filter to run a macro in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am kind of a newbie to programming in Access and there might be an alternative way to do what I intend, but I hope someone can help me.

1. I have a query with 5 fields: Date, Salesperson, Item, Quantity and Value.
2. In my database I have around 600 differente Salesperson
3. I have a report that is linked to the query mentioned on 1. and basically puts the information in a table format, in order to print it.

What I am trying to do is to build a macro that gets Salesperson 1, filters the report with that record on the corresponding field, prints the report to pdf file with the Salesperson name and Date and then goes for the next Salesperson, and so on until it reaches the last Salesperson.

In short, I need to end up with a pdf file for each Salesperson that shows up in the query.

I have searched for a solution, but nothing got close to what I need.

Hope someone can help or at least guide me in a possible way to accomplish this.

Best

Jorge Santos

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code will get a list of names from a table, then run and save the report as a PDF.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Print_Salesman_Report()
Dim strSQL      As String
Dim rs          As DAO.recordSet
Dim dbs         As DAO.Database
Dim strFileName As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
strSQL = "select * from salesperson order by [salesperson name];"       ' Select Salesperson names (if dup's, you need to change sql)
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)          ' Open list of names to process

Do While Not rs.EOF                         ' Repeat until finished
    Debug.Print rs![salesperson name]
    strFileName = "C:\temp\" & rs![salesperson name] & ".pdf"       ' Create file name (modify as needed)
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptSalesperson", acFormatPDF, strFileName, False    ' Run the report

    rs.MoveNext     ' Get next salesperson
Loop

rs.Close            ' Wrap it up.  All Dunn here.
Set rs = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: One additional question: is it possible to generate a pdf password protected?

Comment: Not with my pc at this time, but Google found these ideas...http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=237261